# Room get all Items produces ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I'am trying to migrate my database to Room but everytime when I try to access items from the DB I receive this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

I checked the database with a SQLite browser and there are items in it. Even the SQL Command below works in the tool with the downloaded DB from device (emulator).

Inside my Dao i have this method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ITEMS")
Single<List<Item>> getItems();
```

While implementing I follow the below codelab from Google: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0

Does anyone know why this error may occur?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: This can be closed. Some legacy code is responsible for this error and it has nothing to do with room. Sorry for the post.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1`
 
We know your array length is 1 from this `Exceptioin`. The max index should be is 0 instead of 1